# radius between 2 arcs

Tags: algorithm, excel, rounded-corners, vba

Looking for an algorithm to calculate the intersection points of the corner radius between 2 arcs. Intersection point, centres and radius of both arcs are known. Radius of corner rad is also known.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly easy: the center of the fillet is located a distance `r` from both arcs, hence on circles of radii `r'-r` and `r"-r`, with the same centers. Just compute the intersection of these circles.

[image]

The tangency points are located on the lines that join the centers, hence you readily obtain the delimiting angles.

Comment: Yup. Got it. Not sure why I didn't think of that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JamesW Believe it or not, MS Word.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two intersecting circles with centers located at (*X*<sub>1</sub>, *Y*<sub>1</sub>) and (*X*<sub>2</sub>, *Y*<sub>2</sub>) and radii *R*<sub>1</sub> and *R*<sub>2</sub>:

> (*x* - *X*<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (*y* - *Y*<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = *R*<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>
>   (*x* - *X*<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (*y* - *Y*<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = *R*<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>

To join these circles with a circular fillet of radius *R*<sub>f</sub>, you need to find the fillet center coordinates (*X*<sub>f</sub>, *Y*<sub>f</sub>) that satisfy the following simultaneous equations:

> (*X*<sub>1</sub> - *X*<sub>f</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (*Y*<sub>1</sub> - *Y*<sub>f</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = (*R*<sub>1</sub> - *R*<sub>f</sub>)<sup>2</sup>
>   (*X*<sub>2</sub> - *X*<sub>f</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (*Y*<sub>2</sub> - *Y*<sub>f</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = (*R*<sub>2</sub> - *R*<sub>f</sub>)<sup>2</sup>

This shouldn't be too difficult. If you need help solving it, perhaps [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/) would be a good place to ask.

Comment: Ended up solving it the geometric way. Simultaneous quadratic equations are over 30 yrs ago - they have slipped away over time for me. I'm keen to follow up though as it would be much simpler. Thanks for you help.